# Developing T.120 protocol in Python

Tags: python, sockets, pygtk

I am creating a chat application which supports chat, group chat, file sharing, whiteboard(not mandatory). I make it own to contribute fedora. if anyone wants to join to grow it welcome(shantanubanerjee75@gmail.com). Netmeeting works on T.120 protocol but didn't find any way to use it. Is there any protocol in linux which support my requirements? is there any way to write a own application protocol in python with few headers? I need it very much..
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jabber protocol](http://www.jabber.org/) may suit your needs (not sure about the whiteboard part). There are many implementations of client and servers in many languages including python.

If you want a more generic aproach you may try with [telepathy](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

There is also a more low level aproach [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple). I did not found any recent libpurple binding for python but you may try to build your own with [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Also take a look at [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/6752) question in launchpad for some other alternatives.

If you really want to develop a new protocol from scratch my take will be to add it to telepathy and use it through Empathy.